# how to enable time for multiDatesPicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

im using the multi date picker from http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/ for an application im building and it works perfectly. I am currently able to select multiple dates and they end up in a text field like this:

2012-10-16,2012-10-17,2012-10-24,2012-10-26,2012-10-27

I need to do multi datepicker with time so i can get results like this:

2012-10-16 13:00:00,2012-10-17 21:30:00,2012-10-24 06:45:00,2012-10-26 08:23:00,2012-10-27 11:00:00

I can seem to find where there is either a way to turn on time for the multi datepicker or some other plugin that allows date and time.

Here is my jquery for multiDatesPicker but timeformat doesnt seem to enable time for me

```
$(function() {
$('#simpliest-usage').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm'  // time format here

});
});
```

The html

```
<input type="text" id="simpliest-usage" name="eDates">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiDatesPicker makes use of the jQuery UI datepicker widget, which only does dates, not times. So multiDatesPicker has the same limitation.

There's a third-party timepicker widget that builds on at http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/. It doesn't automatically add these features to the datepicker widget, so you'll need to modify multiDatesPicker to use it. Maybe just doing a global replace of `datepicker` to `datetimepicker` will do it.